# Get-Content and Set-Content with specific lines and seperated

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm using the following code to find a line containing a string in a very large csv file, then printing the rows where the string is to a .log file.

I'm using the following code...

```
$fileContents = Get-Content $testReport -TotalCount 1
$fileContents += Get-Content $testReport -ReadCount 1000 | ForEach {$_ -match $myString}
$fileContents | Set-Content 'C:\Temp\test1.log'
```

Instead of getting the following:

```
firstLine
line
line
line
```

I'm getting this:

```
firstLine
linelineline
```

Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is the best way...

```
Import-Csv $testReport | 
    Where-Object {$_.columnName -eq $myString} | 
        Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\test1.log' -NoTypeInformation -Force
```